# Create a broswer to load website in a web page in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, browser

I have an odd question. Currently I am creating an ASP.NET MVC web application and I would like to be able to load a different website inside one of my web pages.

e.g. A user would navigate to my page such as index.aspx this will load my menu navigation and it will also load a different website inside some sort of frame.

I know that when making window forms applications you can create a browser to open webpages so I am hoping this is possible in ASP.NET.

Sorry if its a silly question. 
Thanks :)

Comment: You can use an `<iframe>` element for that, but be aware that some websites will refuse to load that way, and the code in your page will be unable to interact with the content.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted some information about the direction to go to achieve this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by `load website` you meant to load web page that is not part of your application, I know that most people use `<iframe>`.

Just a short example how you can you do it:

```js
<iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
  <span>iframe is not supported.</span>
</iframe>
```

But, if you meant to load a web page from your application, then you need to render partial views.

```js
[HttpGet]
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult PartialName()
{
  return PartialView();  
}
```

and call it in your layout like this:

```js
@Html.Action("PartialName", "ControllerName")
```

Hope this helps. :)